# Weird behavior in regular expression replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre

I'm doing a regular expression for a linking system, and the syntax looks like this:

```
<a href=":login">Login</a>
```

This tells the system that this link should be converted to JS or an HTML destination depending on the user's browser capabilities.

Right, so I have all the back-end stuff working fine, but I noticed a strange problem with the regular expresion that I'm using to catch these types of links. When a dynamic link (href=":) stands by itself (i.e. not next to another  object) then it works fine; however, if a dynamic link like

```
<a href=":myLink">
```

comes after a standard link like

```
<a href="myLink">
```

then the dynamic link doesn't get altered, like it should.

Here is a codepad link to some sample code that demonstrates the bug. 
http://codepad.org/ZKdm2NkS

Notice the `<a href=":first">` link does not get modified but the `<a href=":second">` link does.

I'm not very good with regexps so I'm sure there's a better way of handling things rather than just using a `(.*)` everywhere you turn, but like I said, I'm open to better ideas and opinions.

Comment: Why use regex here instead of parsing the DOM?

Comment: Ungreedy regexes help a little, Mike's suggestion of  using a `DOM` parser helps more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the only thing you are replacing is the ":myLink" portion you don't really need to match the rest... try this:

```
$html = preg_replace('/href=":([\w]+)"/', 'href="processedLink-$1"', $html);
```

this is matching only word (\w) characters (letters, digits, underscores)